# Como realizar loop com while usando array

Tags: php, array, mysqli, foreach, while

Ola gostaria de saber se e possível realizar um loop utilizando `while` da seguinte forma necessito que os valores da array `$newsmedias1` seja colocado no `while` de forma a realizar a aparição dos itens com os IDS determinados na `Array` desde que eles sejam iguais aos IDS da tabela medias coluna id. Eu estou realizando o loop atualmente com uso do `foreach`.

A `$news['valores']` contem números da tabela news coluna valores separados por virgula exemplo 256,458,300 etc esses valores são os ids correspondentes da tabela medias coluna id desta forma ao aplicar estes valores aplica eles ao explode depois realiza o loop.

**Codigo com uso do foreach**

```
<?php

    // IDS da Tabela media coluna valores
        $newsmedias1 = trim($news['valores'], ', ' );

    // Aplica explode para separar os valores por virgula
        $newsmedias2 = explode("," , $newsmedias1); 

    // Filtra somente valores completos
        $mediaID = array_filter($newsmedias2);  

    foreach ($mediaID as $item) 
{
    $sql = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT * FROM medias WHERE id = '$item'");
    $row = $sql->fetch_array()
    echo $nome;

}   
 ?>
```

O problema e que este modo não esta sendo muito eficiente pois se eu quiser mostrando 45 itens realizara 45 consultas e isso esta pesando muito gostaria de fazer funcionar usando `while` de forma a realizar uma única consulta mostrando todos os resultados da mesma forma do uso do foreach.

Comment: Tentou um `WHERE IN(?,? ... ?)` ?

Comment: Não entendi por que o `WHERE IN` não se aplica no seu caso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como dito pelo @rray, você pode fazer isso utilizando `WHERE IN`

Assim:

```
SELECT * FROM medias WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Outra possível forma seria usando a função implode, para unir os elementos do `array` e criar a sintaxe correta para o `IN`

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM medias WHERE id IN(%s)", implode(', ', array(1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: Eu dei uma atualizada na pergunta o problema e que necessito que a $news['valores'] seja aplicada na where eu havia colocado valores numéricos separados por virgula na $news['valores'] para ficar mais explicativo e quando eu tentei por a $news['valores'] dentro de in deu erro. `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object`

Comment: Agradeço ai pela ajuda foi extremamente útil ambas as respostas suas. Funcionou a primeira alternativa perfeitamente o que eu tive que fazer foi so por a `$newsmedias1` dentro do IN pois no caso demais parâmetros são usado para realizar calculo para fazer aparecer texto no singular o plural.

Answer (score 1):

Na query sql vc pode passa o array ...

`query("SELECT * FROM medias WHERE id in( "+ $mediaID +");` ,

ai é so tira do foreach